# Git create a empty branch from existing repository

Tags: git, branch

I have a git repository which has many branches my requirement is to create a new empty branch so that its independent of the earlier branches.

Comment: You mean like a new repository, containing nothing at all? Or like a new branch depending on the main branch, one that includes all merged code?

Comment: @GolezTrol My current project requirement is to revamp the code which we call it as a legacy and create a new project from scratch which will be a newer version. I want to use the same repository which was used for legacy but should have a clean branch.

Comment: Create a new repo. If you want to do it from scratch, you'll have no common commits and having two totally different code bases in one repo is pointless.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's not a good practice, but if you want really start with a new branch without relation to master you must use **--orphan** argument of checkout :

```
git checkout --orphan version2
# and remove your project files
```

You'll get more detail about **--orphan** arguments in the doc : http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout

Comment: Thanks for the solution.But  I think creating a new repository will be better solution. Since i cannot merge the orphan code with any of the branch.

Comment: It sounds like a better solution. Good luck ;)

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work fine for adding a gh-pages to github

Answer (score 5):

### 2022 Update

As of Git 2.23, you can use `git switch --orphan <new branch>` to create an empty branch with no history. Unlike `git checkout --orphan`, all **tracked** files will be removed.

Once you actually have commits on this branch, it can be pushed to the remote repository:

```bash
git switch --orphan <new branch>
git commit --allow-empty -m "Initial commit on orphan branch"
git push -u origin <new branch>
```

More details about the **switch** option in the documentation : https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch

Answer (score -3):

Create the branch on your local machine and switch in this branch

```
$ git checkout -b [name_of_your_new_branch]
```

Push the branch on github :

```
$ git push origin [name_of_your_new_branch]
```

You can all branches with current working branch with * mark by using below command:

```
$ git branch
```

Also You can find complete list of all git branching and merging files [Create a new branch with git and manage branches](https://github.com/Kunena/Kunena-Forum/wiki/Create-a-new-branch-with-git-and-manage-branches)

Comment: Curious as to why this is considered bad practice? Seems to be the most straightforward way. What are the caveats if you do this?

Comment: @geofrey, I know it's been a long time since you asked.. the reason is that the new branch will not be empty, it will contain all the commits committed prior to creating the new branch