# Bitbucket git push tag --no-verify results is pre-receive declined because someone else has an LFS lock on a file

Tags: git, locking, bitbucket, hook, push

We have a release script that creates a branch, pulls in the commits necessary and then performs a commit and push of a tag.  Originally we did not use the --no-verify push option but changed after discovering that the push failed if someone else had an LFS lock on an unrelated file. Adding the --no-verify apparently did not prevent the pre-release hook from executing.

The code works fine if nobody else has LFS locks on any file in the repository.

Here is the code and the error received:

```
git branch release-TEST
git checkout release-TEST
git pull origin master
git rm -rf .
git checkout 09695c3b10961914f252aba854af1cfbefdcf995 'SANDBOX_proj/Baseline test/Baseline test 2.txt'
git cat-file blob '09695c3b10961914f252aba854af1cfbefdcf995:SANDBOX_proj/Baseline test/Baseline test 2.txt'
git lfs smudge
git checkout 0033b47eeac61aafbb76771de607fa0141fbde0f 'SANDBOX_proj/Baseline test/Baseline test 1.txt'
git cat-file blob '0033b47eeac61aafbb76771de607fa0141fbde0f:SANDBOX_proj/Baseline test/Baseline test 1.txt'
git lfs smudge
git commit -a -m TEST
git tag -a TEST -m 'SANDBOX project version TEST'
git push --no-verify origin TEST
```

### error output from push, no previous errors

remote: Push rejected because of LFS lock
remote: Changes were made to the file 'SANDBOX_proj/Other Test/Test4.txt', which is locked by someone else (someone.else@mmm.com)
To https://bitbucket.mmm.com/scm/mmm-yyy/SANDBOX.git
! [remote rejected] TEST -> TEST (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to https://bitbucket.mmm.com/scm/mmm-yyy/SANDBOX.git

I would appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: What kind of thoughts do you want? Why not just ask the person to unlock the file?

Comment: Different shift, schedule, can't reach - my real  question was why the --no-verify does not work.  Regardless, I found a beffer solution here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32559168/git-create-a-empty-branch-from-existing-repository

Comment: You can always force unlock files that people have not released